# I'm not able to boot to Windows after installing Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: uefi, lenovo

I have Lenovo G50 laptop and I installed ubuntu to my system in different
drive.

When the grub comes and clicks on "Windows" I get an error message which tells that "The current hardware and software installation makes unable to load windows"(Boot priority is 'legacy first' in BIOS settings).

But when I change the boot option to UEFI then am able to get windows but not the ubuntu. When the boot option is "Legacy support" and
boot priority is "Legacy first" am able to get the Ubuntu but not the Windows.

So can anybody tell me that how the BIOS settings supposed to be in Lenovo G50 and ways to get windows and ubuntu together?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you have this issue is because Windows was installed with EFI and Ubuntu with Legacy mode and these two both *Love* to cause problems with one another. Your best bet is to back up your Ubuntu data and reinstall it in EFI mode.

Comment: A lot of sites give the *bad advice* to enable BIOS/CSM/legacy support in the firmware before installing Ubuntu. This advice often leads to exactly the problem you (Jerin) have. If you made this mistake, undo the firmware mode change to enable *only* EFI-mode booting. You can then either re-install or run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix the problem. For more on this subject, see [my Web page about it.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

Comment: But the boot option DVD drive is not available when it is in EFI model in my computer. to get the DVD option I have to shift the boot option from EFI to legacy support

Comment: Try putting Ubuntu on a flash drive in startup disk creator or (if for some reason) you don't have a flash drive/usb support then try booting the cd with the refund boot loader